# what is the latest required hash rate to mine a block?

Tags: mining-reward

What is the latest required hash rate to mine a block of bitcoin ?

How much power do you need to mine a block in a day ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can estimate the value with "getnetworkhashps" command

> What is the latest required hash rate to mine a block of bitcoin ?

26,592,872 trillions of hashes per second

> How much power do you need to mine a block in a day ?

average hash power of 1 day is 35,683,280 trillions of hashes per second

```
$ date --utc
Sat Feb 16 12:23:48 UTC 2019

// 1 block
$ curl --user 'id:password' --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getnetworkhashps","params":[1]}' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332
{"result":2.659287272432074e+19,"error":null,"id":"curltext"}

// average of 144 blocks (about 144 blocks are generated in a day)
$ curl --user 'id:password' --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getnetworkhashps","params":[144]}' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332
{"result":3.568328058845101e+19,"error":null,"id":"curltext"}
```

// chainquery.com (I think a little bit buggy sometimes)

http://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/getnetworkhashps

// blockchain.com hash rate

https://www.blockchain.com/ja/charts/hash-rate